# Import js/css to jsp in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project, I can import css/js to my index.jsp but not for the others views.
I tried ${pageContext.request.contextPath} but it did not work.

I have this structure.

[image]

**Servlet**

```
resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme1/"
```

**views/*.jsp**

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Message Page</title>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

 <script src="<c:url value="/resources/css/messages.js" />"></script>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/js/messages.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

In browser log i get:

GET http://localhost:8080/ProyectTest/resources/css/messages.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 –
GET http://localhost:8080/ProyectTest/resources/js/messages.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: in browser console does it throw 404 ?

Comment: Please specify exact error

Comment: In browser log: GET http://localhost:8080/ProyectTest/resources/css/messages.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: css , js folder reversed !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got your problem in line

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/js/messages.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Look carefully. Your css file is inside `css` folder, but you declared path for `js` folder.
I think using this line will work for you.

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/messages.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: @Alberto. Hehe. It's ok. It happens!